# in IntelliJ Idea " jade.Boot" as main class doesnt work

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to create a class that extends Agent in "intellij Idea" . if I choose "jade.Boot" for main class in "edit configuration" ,it doesnt work and gets error.

```
public class Agent1 extends Agent
{
    protected void setup()
    {
         System.out.println("Hello World. ");
         System.out.println("My name is "+ getLocalName());
    }
}
```

(edit configuration)

Main class: jade.Boot

program arguments: -gui -local-port 1100 MyAgent:Agent1

////apply and run

I also created a loopback test network

it shows this error:

```
SEVERE: Some problem occurred while joining agent platform.
jade.core.ServiceException: Error while booting mandatory service 
jade.core.messaging.Messaging - Caused by:  jade/util/BasicProperties      
atjade.core.AgentContainerImpl.bootAllServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:478)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:410)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:502)
at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
Nested Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jade/util/BasicProperties
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
atjade.core.messaging.MessagingService$CommandTargetSink.installMTP(Messagin
gService.java:1264)
atjade.core.messaging.MessagingService$CommandTargetSink.handleInstallMTP(Me
ssagingService.java:1176)
atjade.core.messaging.MessagingService$CommandTargetSink.consume(MessagingSe
rvice.java:1055)
at jade.core.CommandProcessor$SinksFilter.accept(CommandProcessor.java:253)
at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:89)
at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
at jade.core.CommandProcessor.processIncoming(CommandProcessor.java:229)
at jade.core.BaseNode.serveVerticalCommand(BaseNode.java:163)
at jade.core.BaseNode.serveHorizontalCommand(BaseNode.java:111)
at jade.imtp.leap.NodeLEAP.accept(NodeLEAP.java:60)
at jade.core.messaging.MessagingProxy.installMTP(MessagingProxy.java:151)
at jade.core.messaging.MessagingService.boot(MessagingService.java:337)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.bootAllServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:470)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:410)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:502)
at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jade.util.BasicProperties
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
Oct 16, 2017 11:19:25 PM jade.core.messaging.MessageManager shutdown
INFO: MessageManager shutting down ...
Oct 16, 2017 11:19:25 PM jade.core.Runtime$1 run
INFO: JADE is closing down now.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it's because of jdk version? or some reason else

Comment: Don't post code and errors as links to images. Post them as text.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited my question